# How to set password protection for PDF files generated with PDFKit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried providing a password option like `PDFKit.new(:password => "foo")` but it won't set any password protection.

I want to set a password protection to PDFs by using PDFKit. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

PDFKit uses [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) in the background which [does not support](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=815) generating password protected PDF files.

If the PDF file contains sensitive data you might want to try encrypting the PDF file after generation.